# How to obtain the value of h:inputHidden element whose value is calculated using jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

My requirement is when the user clicks the submit button, a new value calculated should be stored in the inputHidden field value. I have written function in jQuery to calculate the new value for the inputHidden field, when submit button is clicked. The new value is assigned to the inputHidden field value. But the problem is that while retrieving the value in the backing bean using hidden.getValue(), it returns null value.

```
    jQuery code:
    function hidden(){
    var valueCalculated = '3';
    $('#hidden').val(valueCalculated);
    alert($('#hidden').val());  //displays 3 when submit button is clicked.
    }

   JSF code:
   <h:inputHidden binding="#{bean.hidden}"/>
```

In the backing bean,
I have getters and setters for hidden of type HTMLInputHidden, and I retrieve the hidden value by using getValue().
This should return the valueCalculated but it returns null.
What is the way to obtain the calculated value in the backing bean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `HtmlInputHidden#getValue()` will only return the submitted value when you're inside the invoke action phase. It's namely been set during the update model values phase. So if you're trying to get it during bean's construction or during other JSF phase *before* invoke action phase, you will get `null`.

To fix this, rewrite the code logic so that it is been accessed at the right moment; in the command button/link action method. Otherwise you have to get it manually from the request parameter map instead.

E.g.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden id="hidden" value="#{bean.hidden}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" onclick="$('#form\\:hidden').val('foo')" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void submit() {
    // Here, in the bean's action method, it should already be set.
    System.out.println(hidden); // "foo"
}
```

Comment: @BalusC: I am accessing the value in the action method itself. But I get a null value. If I go back to the login page only in Mozilla and login again, the hidden value is set with the previously calculated value.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Try using `value` instead of `binding` as in my answer.

Comment: @BalusC: I am using JSF 2.0 version. I will use value and check if it is working as you told. Thank you for the information provided.

Comment: "JSF 2.0" is just the spec version. Which impl? Mojarra? MyFaces? ADF? Something else? And which version? Mojarra 2.0.5? MyFaces 2.0.2? Or maybe even Mojarra 2.1.1? etc.

Comment: Works fine here. Your problem is caused by something else. Maybe you don't have a `<h:form prependId="false">` at all. Maybe the `$('#hidden')` does not point to the real hidden input (open page in browser, view source and check generated HTML id). Maybe you're accessing the wrong property in the bean. Etc..etc..